# Using Dygraphs in frameset

Tags: javascript, php, html, dygraphs

I made a page with Dygraph graphics. It works great. When I try to call it in frameset it throws following error: "Object is not supporting the property or method "defineProperty"" (original in german: "Das Objekt unterstützt die Eigenschaft oder Methode "defineProperty" nicht."). I use Dygraphs Version 2.0, error points on line 6410 in dygraphs.js.
Here the definition of frameset:

```
<frameset cols="220,*" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
<frame src="./nav.php" name="rep_visu_nav" noresize scrolling="auto">
<frame src="./main.php" name="rep_visu_main">
</frameset>
```

Here the header of the page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
        <!--<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">-->

        <!--[if IE]>
                <script src="path/to/excanvas.js">
                </script>
        <![endif]-->

        <title>OEE</title>
        <meta charset='windows-1252'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
        <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />
        <link rel=stylesheet' media='print' type='text/css' href='../include/css/noprint_1020.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../include/graph-bib/dygraph2/dygraph.css">
        <script  type="text/javascript" 
                 src="../../include/graph-bib/dygraph2/dygraph.js">

        </script>
    </head>
```

And here the generated code of graph:

```
    <div id="graphdiv1" style="width:1400px; height:250px; text-align: right;"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
var data = "2017/02/01,87.68,81.34\n" + 
"2017/02/02,72.87,81.34\n" + 
"2017/02/03,79,81.34\n";
                        function formatDate(d) {
                            var yyyy = d.getFullYear(),
                                    mm = d.getMonth() + 1,
                                    dd = d.getDate();
                            return (dd < 10 ? '0' : '') + dd + '.' + (mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + mm + '.' + yyyy;
                        }
                        g = new Dygraph(
                                // containing div
                                document.getElementById("graphdiv1"),
                                // CSV or path to a CSV file.
                                data,
                                {
                                    labels: ['Datum', 'OEE', 'Ziel'],
                                    colors: ['blue', 'red'],
                                    ylabel: 'OEE %',
                                    xlabel: 'Datum',
                                    title: 'OEE - Aktueller Monat',
                                    legend: 'allways',
                                    valueRange: [30, 100],
                                    axes: {
                                        x: {
                                            valueFormatter: function (ms) {
                                                return formatDate(new Date(ms));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                        );
                    </script>
```

Any ideas whats wrong? Outside of frameset is verythng working fine.
I get the same error with Dygraph Version 1.1.1...

Comment: I made some tests. It´s only IE Problem. In Firefox is frameset working.